# how to search until the last /

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this url

```
http://abc.com.ppd-www.abccom.server.net/info/first/abccom/office/About_abc        /abc_Information/ABC_Informatio_Press_News/Images                      /Here%20You%20Can%20Get%20More%20Related%202012%20News%20About%20FINAL.pdf
```

I was looking for a regex to search until the last `/` and also eliminate `%20`. I want to finally have

```
here you can get more related 2012 news about final
```

I tried many possible expressions but was unsuccessful.

Thanks

Comment: Which language or tool do you use? What are your capitalization rules? Why does everything go to lower case except for the `N` in `News`?

Comment: What programming language is this in context of? There is likely to be a better way than regex, and a method to decode the URL.

Comment: using javascript, no capitalization rules

Comment: You don't need a regex, since you know what your delimiter is. Simply `split`/`explode`/whatever the string into an array and take the last element.

Comment: I don't see how you would end up with `here you can get more related 2012 news about final`, starting with `http://abc.com.ppd-www.abccom.server.net/info/first/abccom/office/About_abc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for regular expressions here. Simply using the built-in functions to manipulate strings and arrays is enough:

```
var parts = str.split('/');
var result = decodeURIComponent(parts[parts.length-1].split('.').slice(0,-1).join(''));
```

This will take everything between the last `/` and the last `.` If you only want to go until the first `.` (or you are sure that there will always just be a single `.` in the file name):

```
var parts = str.split('/');
var result = decodeURIComponent(parts[parts.length-1].split('.')[0]);
```

Just if you are curious, here is the regular expression solution:

```
var result = str.match(/\/([^\/]*)\.pdf$/)[1].replace(/%20/g, ' ');
```

But you cannot tell me that this is more readable/maintainable ;).